# How to display List<> using ListView?

Tags: android, list, listview

When I use ListView to display a array of my object, I can use the following code:

```
MyObject[] myObject;
...  
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> itemList = new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>(this, R.layout.list, myObject);   
setListAdapter(itemList);
```

In case that the input is a list:

```
List<MyObject> myobject;
```

How can I assign it to ListAdapter? Please advise, Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There is another constructor for ArrayAdapter that takes in a list:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

See [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) java doc for a complete list!

Comment: But I can't use the code:
setListAdapter(itemList);

Because setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<MyObject>) is undefined!

Comment: You are referring to the function in ListActivity: public void  setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)?  ArrayAdapter<T> extends from ListAdapter, so you can provide an ArrayAdapter<T> instance to that function... Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Even the question seems already to be answered, i'd like to mention using custom listviews with a custom adapter:

There is a great tutorial how to use a listview

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327

a second tutorial (in 6 parts) you can find here:

http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/